# Correct use of currentTarget for a click event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I built this little example. I have some elements and for some of this there is a discount of 15%. I want to push this value (15% of the price) into an Array when "buy" is pressed and only if the pressed item has a discount.

The idea was to use currentTarget to recognize which item has a discount and which not, but my function returns in the console always the same message: "This item has NO discount" and of course nothing is pushed into the array.

I'm using currentTarget in a wrong way? I tried to use also $(this) instead of e.currentTarget but nothing changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');
  var discountCustomer = [];

  function addItem() {
    if($event.find('.discount').length) {
      var $discount = ((parseInt($event.find('.price').text()))*15)/100;
      console.log($discount);
      discountCustomer.push($discount);
      
      $totalDiscount=0;
      for (var i = 0; i < discountCustomer.length; i++) {
        $totalDiscount += discountCustomer[i] << 0;
      }
      
      $('.totalDiscount').html(($totalDiscount) + ' €');
      
    } else {
      console.log('This seminar has NO discount');
    }
    console.log(discountCustomer);
  }

  $('.buy').click(function() {
    addItem();
    })
})
```

```css
.event {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.event > * {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.total > * {
  float: left;
}

.totalDiscount {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="discount">This seminar has a discount!</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="discount">This seminar has a discount!</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="total">
  <p>Total Discount: </p>
  <p class="totalDiscount"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `ready` take an event variable? I think the execution is flawed. Event variables are populated on click, mouseover, etc, but I don't think `ready` does this.

Comment: Also, just a thought, but if you're querying the DOM for information (such as discounts) you're going to build a product that's hard to maintain and open for manipulation. Pricing information should probably be stored in an array and retrieved from the API. This makes it easier to query the information you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, but the project where i'm working now has this kind of approach and I can't change it. That's why I have to make it work in this way.

Comment: Ah gotcha, understood :) The two posted answers should give you what you need then. Just gotta capture the event where it's actually capturable :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass `e` to the `addItem` function also `var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');` should come inside `addItem` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    var discountCustomer = [];

  function addItem(e) {
    var $event = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');
    if($event.find('.discount').length) {
      var $discount = ((parseInt($event.find('.price').text()))*15)/100;
      console.log($discount);
      discountCustomer.push($discount);
      
      $totalDiscount=0;
      for (var i = 0; i < discountCustomer.length; i++) {
        $totalDiscount += discountCustomer[i] << 0;
      }
      
      $('.totalDiscount').html(($totalDiscount) + ' €');
      
    } else {
      console.log('This seminar has NO discount');
    }
    console.log(discountCustomer);
  }

  $('.buy').click(function(e) {
    addItem(e);
 })
})
```

```css
.event {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.event > * {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.total > * {
  float: left;
}

.totalDiscount {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="discount">This seminar has a discount!</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="discount">This seminar has a discount!</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="total">
  <p>Total Discount: </p>
  <p class="totalDiscount"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfekt, it does exactly what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are not capturing the click event, I did this little modification to capture it (and passing the current element) to addItem function... Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
  
  var discountCustomer = [];

  function addItem($event) {
    if($event.find('.discount').length) {
      var $discount = ((parseInt($event.find('.price').text()))*15)/100;
      console.log($discount);
      discountCustomer.push($discount);
      
      $totalDiscount=0;
      for (var i = 0; i < discountCustomer.length; i++) {
        $totalDiscount += discountCustomer[i] << 0;
      }
      
      $('.totalDiscount').html(($totalDiscount) + ' €');
      
    } else {
      console.log('This seminar has NO discount');
    }
    console.log(discountCustomer);
  }

  $('.buy').click(function(e) {
  var $event = $(e.target).closest('.event');
    addItem($event);
 })
})
```

```css
.event {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.event > * {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.total > * {
  float: left;
}

.totalDiscount {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="discount">This seminar has a discount!</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="discount">This seminar has a discount!</div>
  <div class="price">10 €</div>
  <button class="buy">Buy</button>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="total">
  <p>Total Discount: </p>
  <p class="totalDiscount"></p>
</div>
```